# Hibernate Child table saves null foreign key instead of auto increment parent's primary key

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate

I'm trying to save to two parent and child table at the same time. It does save the both parent and child rows but the issue is child table doesn't contain the primary key(Auto Increment) of parent table in foreign key column in child table. Instead of that foreign key column in child table shows null

here are the Models
01.Feed Order class (Parent Class)

```
@Entity
public class FeedOrder {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    private String date;
    private double total;
    private double discount;


    @OneToMany(mappedBy="feedOrder",cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
    private List<FeedOrderDetail> feedOrderDetail;

    @ManyToOne
    private Supplier supplier;
    //With Getters and Setters
}
```

02.Feed Order Details class (Child Class)

```
@Entity
public class FeedOrderDetail {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    private double unitPrice;
    private long quantity;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="feed_id")
    private Feed feed;


    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="order_id")
    private FeedOrder feedOrder;
    //With Getters and Setters
}
```

I use Spring MVC as well.

Here is the Repository class Code.

```
@Repository("feedOrderRepository")
public class FeedOrderRepositoryImp implements FeedOrderRepository {

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager em;

    public FeedOrder save(FeedOrder feedOrder) {

        em.persist(feedOrder);
        em.flush();

        return null;
    }

}
```

### Update

AddFeedOrder.jsp

```
<html>
<body>
<form:form commandName="feedOrder">

    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Date</td>
            <td><form:input path="date" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Discount</td>
            <td><form:input path="discount" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Total</td>
            <td><form:input path="total" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Supplier</td>
            <td><form:input path="supplier.id" /></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <table id="mytable">
        <tr>
            <td>Feed ID</td>
            <td>Unit Price</td>
            <td>Quantity</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><form:input path="feedOrderDetail[0].feed.id" /></td>
            <td><form:input path="feedOrderDetail[0].unitPrice" /></td>
            <td><form:input path="feedOrderDetail[0].quantity" /></td>
        </tr>

    </table>
    <INPUT type="button" value="Add More" onclick="addRow('mytable')" />
    <tr>
        <td><input type="submit" value="Save Feed Order"></td>
    </tr>

</form:form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you populated the feedOrder property of FeedOrderDetail? I guess not.

Comment: Please show the code where you create the instances of FeedOrder and FeedOrderDetail.

Comment: @JBNizet how can I populate with jsp page.I want to save it as one transaction.

Comment: That's not the JSP's job. That's the job of the Java code, in the service or controller.

Comment: @JBNizet I'm really new to hibernate.I wish you could give me a help.

Comment: Well, somewhere in the Java code, before persisting the entities, make sure that each FeedOrderDetails has its feedOrder set. It's simple Java: `for (FeedOrderDetails detail : feedOrder.getDetails()) { detail.setFeedOrder(feedOrder); }`

Comment: @JBNizet added it in service class. Worked Like a charm. thank you very very much.